# How to read an object from file written by PrintWriter

Tags: java, file, printwriter, objectinputstream

I have to write and read an object from a file:

I used **PrintWriter** to write an object into file and it works

```
PrintWriter pw =  new PrintWriter (filePath + ".object");
pw.print(object);
pw.flush();
pw.close();
```

To read, I am trying to do this:

```
ObjectInputStream objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filepath));
Object response = objectIn.readObject();
```

But it doesn't work.I have the following error:

> invalid stream header: 66756E63

Somebody can help me?? Thanks a lot

Comment: You need to use ObjectOutputStream to write objects to files.

Comment: Why do you even think this would work? What is `object`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - how to read from file when I used PrintWriter, BufferedWriter and FileWriter to write?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135726/java-how-to-read-from-file-when-i-used-printwriter-bufferedwriter-and-filewri)

Comment: Also, did you forget to add ".object" to your FileInputStream path?

Comment: 'Object from file written by `PrintWriter`' is already a contradiction in terms.

Comment: Open that `.object` file in a text editor (Notepad, anything), and you will see what it contains (text). `66756E63` are the ASCII codes from the character sequence `func`. Anyway, the general pairs are `Writer`-`Reader` and `OutputStream`-`InputStream`. When you use something with these endings, and the "opposite" also exists, it is almost sure that they are meant to be used as a pair (and `ObjectOutputStream` indeed exists).